# Does Visual Studio use nvcc to compile cuda codes?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I'm a beginner in GPU programming.
I'm studying cuda through Visual Studio 2019.

When i build some cuda program, does Visual Studio use 'nvcc' to compile?
Or Visual Studio has its own cuda compiler and use it?

It may be a little sloppy because it's my first question.
Thank you.

Comment: Even though CUDA is supported on Windows, it is somewhat easier - in my opinion - to make heads and tails of the CUDA ecosystem on Linux systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, visual studio will use `nvcc` to compile files that end in `.cu`.

You can verify this by looking at the visual studio console output when you build a CUDA sample project like `vectorAdd`.  If you don't see it, turn [the visual studio verbosity up](https://kb.froglogic.com/coco/howto/visualstudio-verbosity/).

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much!